# How to configuring apache CAMEL in KURA framework

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-camel, osgi, rhiot

I am working in Apache camel which has to be included in KURA framework for throttling and some other purposes,so i have followed [this link](http://camel.apache.org/kura.html).
i have provided the KuraRouter(from jar files) as the main class in KURA project instead of HelloOsgi and in component.xml file , start and stop function in that class as Activate and Deactivate methods.But when i run that it displaying following error!MESSAGE

```
Exception occurred while creating new instance of component Component[
    name = org.apache.camel.component.kura.KuraRouter
    activate = start
    deactivate = stop
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = true
    implementation = org.apache.camel.component.kura.KuraRouter
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = null
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi_1.0.0.qualifier [20]
] 
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.component.kura.KuraRouter
```

Is i am wrong in configuration of camel in Kura and is there any good steps for that.

the Manifest.MF file is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Hello world Example With Logger
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ClassPath: .,/junit.jar,
 camel-core-2.15.2.jar,
 camel-core-osgi-2.15.2.jar,
 org.osgi.core-4.3.0.jar,
 slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,
 camel-kura-2.15.2.jar,
 commons-management-1.0.jar,
 apache-activemq-4.1.1.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration;version="0.2.0",
 org.json,
 org.osgi.service.component;version="1.2.0",
 org.slf4j;version="1.6.4",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Service-Component: component.xml
```

and the component.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" activate="start" deactivate="stop" enabled="true" immediate="true" name="org.apache.camel.component.kura.KuraRouter">

 <implementation class="org.apache.camel.component.kura.KuraRouter"/>

</scr:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start Kura Camel project is to use this [1] quickstart. More details can be found here [2].

Feel free to ping me in case of any issues. :)

[1] https://github.com/rhiot/quickstarts/tree/master/kura-camel
[2] https://rhiot.gitbooks.io/rhiotdocumentation/content/quickstarts/kura_camel_quickstart.html